# Why does the segmentation fault occur in the code I wrote?

Tags: c, error-handling

[Problem description]

Enter an integer N (1-10) to create a string array that is the size of N (1-10) x 30, and enter the character and N string you want to find.
Then write a program that returns the number of characters you entered in the entire string.

[Input Example]

```
4
l
apple
love
leaving
lalala
```

[output example]

```
6
```

[My Code]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int char_cnt(char v[10][30], char *ch, int n){
  int count = 0;
  int temp = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){

   for(int j = 0; strlen(v[i]); j++){
     if(v[i][j] == *ch){
       count++;
     }
   }
   temp += count;
  }
 return temp;
}

int main(void) {        
  int cnt=0;
  char v[10][30];  
  int n;
  char find;
  scanf("%d %c", &n, &find);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%s", v[i]);
  }

  printf("%d \n",char_cnt(v,&find, n));  

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop

```
   for(int j = 0; strlen(v[i]); j++){
```

`strlen(v[i])` won't change and it will always be true if `v[i]` is non-empty string. Therefore the loop will go infinitely and when `j` become too large reading of out-of-range `v[i][j]` may cause Segmentation Fault.

What you want should be

```
   for(int j = 0; v[i][j]; j++){
```